# WPF C# DesignSource not working "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in XAML .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-5

[image]

I'm getting this error. .NET version is  .NET 5.0

It has always worked under .net framework but now that i am doing it with .NET 5.0 i'm getting this, can anyone help me?

Comment: If this is only a design issue, its probably just a tooling bug, report it to MS

Comment: I opened a ticked, I hope they answer me soon. In the meantime I hope someone has a solution to share here.